# Magento 2 : How to get custom attribute value from attribute name?

Tags: magento2

How to get custom attribute value from custom attribute name ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for customer entity

```
$customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
$test = $customer->getCustomAttribute("test");
if ($test) {
    $testValue = $test->getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code if want to show the value of a custom attribute on the product pages.

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$customAttributeCode = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attribute_code');
$attributeValue = $customAttributeCode->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
if ($attributeValue) {
    echo '<div><strong>'.Custom Attribute Title.'</strong></div>';
    echo '<p><span>'.$attributeValue.'</span></p>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code to get custom attribute value from custom attribute name.

```
protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

$product = $this->productRepository->get('sku');

$attributeValue = $product->getAttributeText('custom_attribute_code');
```

Comment: `getAttributeText()` is not a method in the `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` class.